# Better way to sum rows

Tags: f#, refactoring, sequence

I'm learning F# (again) and I'm trying to sum some rows in excel. This is my attempt.

```
let sumRows (source: seq<double[]>) =
    source
    |> Seq.reduce (fun a b -> (a, b) ||> Seq.map2 (fun x y -> x + y) |> Seq.toArray)
```

Can it be done better? I already discovered double forward pipe operator, but now, whole part `fun a b -> (a, b) ||>` seems quite redundant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right it is redundant, because the double pipe operator is convenient only when you need to convert a tuple into two separate parameters. In this case you already have them as 2 separate parameters so you could just pass them like this:

```
let sumRows (source: seq<double[]>) =
    source
    |> Seq.reduce (fun a b -> Seq.map2 (fun x y -> x + y) a b |> Seq.toArray)
```

We can get rid of the `|> Seq.toArray` by replacing `Seq.map2` with `Array.map2`:

```
let sumRows (source: seq<double[]>) =
    source
    |> Seq.reduce (fun a b -> Array.map2 (fun x y -> x + y) a b)
```

now we can simplify further by removing the `fun a b ->`:

```
let sumRows (source: seq<double[]>) =
    source
    |> Seq.reduce (Array.map2 (fun x y -> x + y) )
```

Finally, did you know that an operator like `+` can be treated as a 2 parameters function
by putting in parenthesis `(+)`?

```
let sumRows2 (source: seq<double[]>) =
    source
    |> Seq.reduce (Array.map2 (+) )
```

All of this versions have the same signature and they are all correct. You choose whichever suits more your style.

BTW, you maybe tempted to go one further and do this:

```
let sumRows2 = Seq.reduce (Array.map2 (+) )
```

but it causes issues with the famous `Value restriction` error. There are workarounds like adding the type annotation or actually using it somewhere in the code, but the best workaround is to add the parameter, like we had before.

Comment: Oh, this is way better refactoring than I imagined! Ok... thanks a lot ;-).